# Performance wise what is the best way to compare 2 DataTables with approximate 1000 records?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, datatable

Performance wise what is the best way to compare 2 DataTables with approximate 1000 records?

I have looked into `LINQ` and `DataRelation` and googled a lot and was not able to reach a optimum solution for a datatable with only about 1000 records

Comment: What type of comparison are you trying to do?

Comment: compare and get the result in another datatable

Comment: The best way?   The optimum way?

Since there are only 1000 records, performance is not an issue.

Do it as simple and straitforward as possible.

Answer (score 2):

[Compare datatables in c#](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/1407a809-9551-4646-b74d-3dee3535249c/how-to-compare-two-datatables-in-c) :

```
public static DataTable CompareTwoDataTable(DataTable dt1, DataTable dt2)
{ 
      dt1.Merge(dt2);
      DataTable d3 = dt2.GetChanges();    
      return d3;
}
```

I do prefer the above datatable inbuilt methods to achieve such a functionality as LINQ is doing an internal looping over the datatable rows for the process. As rows and columns goes up this may end up with perfomance leaks.